# Trigonometric 0001 sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, trigonometric-series

Need help in generating particular sequence (0001000100010001...) using trigonometric functions formula (e.a. "cos").

For example, the formula for sequence 0101010101... is:
$f(x)=\cos(\pi x/2).$
For sequence 001001001001001.... The formula is: 
$f(x)=(2/3)(\cos(2\pi x/3)+1/2).$

Thanks for any help that can lead to problem solution.

Milovan

Comment: I don't understand... How is the sequence generated again?

Answer (score 2):

Correcting your first example, we have
$$\left\{\cos\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)\right\}=(0,-1,0,1,0,-1,0,1,\ldots)\ .$$
Hence
$$\left\{\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)\right\}=(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,\ldots)\ .$$
Add these two sequences and divide by $2$.

Comment: Thanks David, I noticed that I missed one part. My intention was to write:

Comment: Pressed <Enter> by mistake. My intention was: y=cos((pi*x/2)+pi).

Comment: Your answer is right correction.

Comment: The answer is exactly what I wanted. Can't believe it is so straight forward and simple. Thank you very much!